# Custom task pane support in Office 2003

Tags: c++, ms-office, office-2003, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have created a C++ Office 2007/2010 add-in that exposes a custom task pane via `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer` and by implementing an ActiveX control. This works perfectly.

Now I want to include support for Office 2003. I have managed to add a toolbar button that should open up a task pane but it appears as if `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer::CTPFactoryAvailable` method is not being called.

Are task panes implemented differently in Office 2003? Is there something specific I need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days of testing and research I have come to a conslusion that even though task panes exist in Office 2003, custom task panes are simply not exposed to developers. CTPs can be used in Office 2007+.

Comment: I am curious about how do u create office add-ins using pure C++. :(